# Apache ForceType / SetHandler not responding as expected

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I am trying to force apache to handle a file (or directory of files) as php regardless of file extension.

The link to the file should be as follows,
`Http://mysitehere.info/sig2/name.png`

I have tried,

`<FilesMatch “\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|flv|ico)$”>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

This does not work, returning a broken  image icon with, the name.png filename and a 404 not found when tried with `sig2/name.png/`

I have also tried,

`<Files .+*^$[]()>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>`

I had gotten that .htaccess file content from [ForceType Sethandler Code Why Does This Work](https://serverfault.com/questions/232636/forcetype-sethandler-code-why-does-this-work)
This returned the same results as the first try. Nothing but 404 or a broken image.

I also tried,

`<Files "name.png">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>`

This does "work" but it doesn't do what it **needs** to.  Accessing the image by `name.png` gives me a broken image.  Accessing it by `name.png/` works for some reason that I am unsure of.

I have made sure that AllowOverride All is set in my httpd.conf for the directory of the image(s).
`<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require All Granted
</Directory>`

This should be enough to get Sethandler or ForceType to work I would assume however I still can't get the effect I want.  Note, I do not have mod_rewrite installed to my server.  Also of note that SetHandler and ForceType have the same results when used with `<Files "name.png">`
I am running PHP 5.5.9? and the latest version of Apache2.

With that, am I doing something horribly wrong or do I have a missing module required for sethandler?

Answer (score 0):

I had found out a major mistake in my code that had set the header to text.  This was a fatal error in code and would indeed return a broken image.  Fixed the error and all of the above actually work as they should.